# How do I assign index values in each?

Tags: jquery, json, each, getjson

I'm trying to print json data on my page.My json data is like this.

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "bmw",
            "model": "3.20i",
            "price": "200$"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "mercedes",
            "model": "c200",
            "price": "500$"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is how I bring my Json data to the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "json.php";
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, output) {
                var id = output.id;
                var title = output.title;
                var duration = output.model;
                var price = output.price;
                $("#listview").append("+ id + title +  model +  price +");
            });
        });
    });
```

output is that way.

```
undefined undefined undefined undefined
```

Can I use it in a loop? For example;

```
1 bmw 3.20i 200$
2 mercedes c200 500$
```

Comment: Need to loop over the array `data.cars`

Comment: are you serious? How did I not see this.Thank you.

Comment: When in doubt do some logging of `output` to see what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'json.php',
        method: 'POST',
        success : function(output) {              
            alert(`Data: ${output}`);
            output = output.map(val => {
                return `${val.id} ${val.title} ${val.model} ${val.price}`;
            }).join('<br/>');
            $("#listview").append(output);
        },
        error : function(request,error) {
            alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 error.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: output.map is not a function at Object.success.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missing closure here. You can create a closure around the values. The simplest way to do is for each loop.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
if(Array.isArray(data)) {
    data.forEach((values, index) => {
        const listText = `${values.id} ${values.title} ${values.model} ${values.price}`
        $("#listview").append(listText);
    })
}});
```